# R: Why doesn't as.vector give a vector when given the output of read.table?

Tags: r, vector

On the output of read.table, as.vector produces an m x 1 matrix rather  than a length m vector:

```
# data.txt contains one integer per line and nothing else
dataframe = read.table("data.txt", encoding='UTF-8', header=F)
v = as.vector(dataframe)
is.vector(v)
[1] FALSE
length(v)
[1] 1
dim(v)
[1] 19783     1
```

Comment: you cant coerce a whole dataframe to vector. You only really need to call it `dataframe$V1` and column `V1` (assumed is V1 as you have `header = FALSE`) is extracted as a vector. Alteernatively, as all data frames are lists you can unlist it. Try `is.vector(unlist(dataframe))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summerise the above data types:

- Data frame: A tabular object  where each column can be a different type. A data frame is really a list.
- Matrix: A tabular object where all values must have the same type.
- Vector: A one dimensional object; all values must have the same type.

Hence it doesn't (in general) make sense to convert from a data frame to a vector.

In your example, you can either

```
unlist(dataframe)
```

or convert to a matrix, then use `as.vector`

```
as.vector(data.matrix(dataframe))
```

Comment: "Vector: A one dimensional object; all values must have the same type.".  Not true, at least by this standard (damn formatting...)

` > is.vector(list(1, "a"))`
` [1] TRUE`

Comment: Sometimes I hate R ;) You're correct. What I meant was an atomic vector

Comment: So what the heck is an atomic vector?  I've been using R for years now, and it's only now I realized I have this misunderstanding abut vectors.  To make matters worse, Rcpp type is called "NumericVector" but it doesn't take a list.  I was driving myself crazy because I thought as.vector() does what unlist() actually does.

Comment: It's messy ;) This http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html#vectors gives a good summary

Answer (score 2):

Consider `readLines` instead of `read.table` which imports the one column directly into a vector:

```
data <- readLines(con="data.txt", n=-1L, encoding='UTF-8', warn=FALSE)

is.vector(data)
#[1] TRUE
```